# How can I add my colors that I selected to the color drop-down box?

Tags: microsoft-word

1. What's this drop-down palette of colors called?
2. The colors below don't appear in the palette, and rather than clicking "More Colors" to access these customized colors every time, how can I add them to the palette?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drop-down palette of colors is called color palette / color picker / [the Colors dialog box](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choosing-colors-in-the-colors-dialog-box-c3d59ddf-65a7-4e62-aad7-f7b8d7684a2d). You can't modify the standard colors in the dialog box. That's what makes them standard.

What you should do is modify a style so that it includes the text color that you want.

A couple of suggestions, though...

When you choose a custom color, add it to the grid at the bottom of the Color Picker pane by dragging the individual swatch into the matrix. The custom colors are added to the main color dropdown palettes below the Standard Colors under a caption of Recent Colors. Once used during a Word session any custom colors used will remain in the palette for the remainder of the session.

Even better [IMHO] if you use the same colors consistently: Create Paragraph and/or Character Styles that include the color attribute.